# Why are deb packages redownloaded while installing deb packages locally

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, deb

I have two machines of Ubuntu 16.04.3 systems A and B.

First, I execute `apt update && apt-get install XXX YYY ZZZ` on the machine A and I can get all deb packages at `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Then I copy all of these deb packages from A to B and on the machine B, I execute `apt update && apt install ./debsFromA/*.deb` to install these deb packages locally.

However, I found that the machine B will redownload all of these deb packages from the ubuntu official siteweb (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ etc).

So I have offered all of deb packages, why would it still download them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself I fix this problem by the following method:

1. Download all necessary packages on *machine A* with `apt-get` (to save them in `/var/cache/apt/archive`)
2. Copy contents of `/var/cache/apt/archive/*.deb` from *machine A* to *removable storage*
3. Copy deb-files from *removable storage* to `/var/cache/apt/archive` of *machine B*
4. Run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install <appname1> <appname2> ...` on *machine B* (it will get all deb-files from local `/var/cache/apt/archive` cache)

This method is straightforward and does not use any special software.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). You may need to adapt the the provided details to your very situation, especially if you are not using a GUI.